# Проверить наличие спецсимволов в строке

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

Подскажите как правильно составить выражение для проверки на содержание спецсимволов в строке.
Если строка содержит хоть один спецсимвол "№;% и т.д.", кроме @ то выдать уведомление.

Answer (score 1):

/[тут_нужные_символы]+$/

Comment: @Veon получается если все спецсимволы тогда проверяет, а если не все то не работает

Comment: @Saturn, почему бы не пойти от обратного - **[^@]+**?

Comment: @Saturn: А вы квадратные скобки не забыли? Кроме того, уберите финальный `$`, он вроде бы не нужен и только мешает. Так же не обязателен и `+`.